# rank a case but not duplicate per account

Tags: apex, trigger, validation

We have a Top Case Rank picklist numbers 1-10.  We also have many accounts.  I'm wanting a way to limit how many top cases each account has.

```
Account A
Case A Rank 3
Case B Rank 1
Case C Rank 2
Case D Rank 1
```

I don't want them to have 2 cases Ranked at #1.  I would also like upon save that the error says "Case (case number) is already ranked at #1 for this account, please choose a different rank"

How can I make this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? This should be achievable in either Apex or Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1.**  You can achieve most of the functionality with only point and click configuration as follows:

- You can create a Unique External Id field which is the concatenation of the AccountId + Rank.
- This external id you need to generate with a Workflow/Flow/Process builder.

How this would work: In the example you provided assuming the Accound Id for Account A= '001abc' (not adding 18 digits for simplicity) the External Id field for Case B will be '001abc1'.

When somebody tries to insert Case D, the External Id will be eventually the same and the system will give you an error like the following

[image]

This option does most of the job but doesn't give you many details regarding the conflicting record.
Hint:  the user can use this id, paste it accordingly to the url and navigate to the conflicting record

**Option 2.** Build a custom solution with triggers and an error message which will provide more details to the user

I would go for Option 1 which does not require custom code, is simple to configure and delivers the main requirement.

Comment: Thank you @ManSpan!  I will try option 1 sounds easier!